# How to make Single Column into Rows in Sql Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, rows

Hi i am in confusing state to run an Sql Query, My table looks like this

[image]

from the above image there are two columns. First column consists of Register No of the student. Second Column Consists his/Her Exam Results.**P** States he is passed in the Certain Subject.In the report i want result set like the below. If the Result consists any number he is failed in the following subject.

- **1--->English   2--->Sanskrit   3--->Maths   4--->Science   5--->Social**

i want the result should be like this. Can any body help me in this. i am not getting any idea.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below Query

```
SELECT RegisterNo,'English' AS Subject ,
     CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Result+ SPACE(5),1,1) = 'P' THEN 'Pass'
          WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Result+ SPACE(5),1,1)) = 1 THEN 'Fail'
          ELSE 'Invalid' END AS Result
FROM table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT RegisterNo,'Sanskrit' AS Subject ,
     CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Result+ SPACE(5),3,1) = 'P' THEN 'Pass'
          WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Result+ SPACE(5),3,1)) = 1 THEN 'Fail'
          ELSE 'Invalid' END AS Result
FROM table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT RegisterNo,'Maths' AS Subject ,
       CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Result+ SPACE(5),5,1) = 'P' THEN 'Pass'
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Result+ SPACE(5),5,1)) = 1 THEN 'Fail'
            ELSE 'Invalid' END AS Result
FROM table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT RegisterNo,'Science' AS Subject ,
       CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Result+ SPACE(5),7,1) = 'P' THEN 'Pass'
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Result+ SPACE(5),7,1)) = 1 THEN 'Fail'
            ELSE 'Invalid' END AS Result
FROM table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT RegisterNo,'Social' AS Subject ,
       CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Result+ SPACE(5),9,1) = 'P' THEN 'Pass'
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Result+ SPACE(5),9,1)) = 1 THEN 'Fail'
            ELSE 'Invalid' END AS Result
FROM table1
ORDER BY RegisterNo
```